# How can I calculate the number of grades that are entered by the user are in the range of 70-90?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, range

I am using echo printing to show grades that user enters. If the number entered is not between 0-100 it will show the user that "You entered an invalid number".
I want to calculate how many grades are in the range of 70-90 that the user inputs.

```
if((input) || input == "" || input < 70|| input > 90)
          {
             range = range + 1;
          }
```

I have this statement to calculate the numbers of grades that are between 70-90

```
document.writeln("<h1 style= \"color: magenta\"> The number of valid grades entered is " + counter + ".<br />The number of grades entered that are between 70-90 are: " + range + ".</h1>");
```

This is the code that displays it.
But it is not always correct. Where should I put the if statement above or should I change it?

Comment: Your `if` condition will be true for *any* string. `||` means "OR".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check that a number is between the min and max of the range, you would likely want to check that it is **both** higher than the min (`input > 70`) and (`&&`) lower than the max (`input < 90`):

```js
var grades = [28, 39, 42, 56, 63, 71, 76, 80, 92, 99, 100];
var min = 70;
var max = 90;

var inRange = grades.filter(function(input) {
  return input > min && input < max;
}).length;
console.log(inRange + ' of the ' + grades.length + ' are in between ' + min + ' and ' + max + '.');
```

Comment: I did it as you said but it is still not working. I entered 88, 78, 67 and 234 it said "The number of grades entered that are between 70-90 = 0

Comment: That was my bad. I put the if statement in a wrong place. I put the statement that you wrote in your first comment and put it in the correct place. It is now working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Better use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) instead of generating a filtered result and get the length of it.

This proposal assumes, that the given values are inclusive, like `min <= x <= max`.

```js
var grades = [28, 39, 42, 56, 63, 71, 76, 80, 92, 99, 100],
    min = 70,
    max = 90,
    inRange = grades.reduce(function(count, input) {
        return count + (input >= min && input <= max);
    }, 0);

console.log(inRange + ' of the ' + grades.length + ' are in between ' + min + ' and ' + max + '.');
```